# How to ask HR to extend my joining date before my offer letter was issued

Tags: human-resources, job-acceptance

I've been working in a company for 3 years and recently i was hired for another company and i said that my notice period was 30 days.

They sent me a salary breakup today and asked me to acknowledge.
As it is ok for me but the thing is my current company set my relieving date on a particular day and the very next day was my committed week of joining,and I hardly need 1 week to switch, but officially I haven't received offer letter.

So how can I request my HR to concern my request while issuing my joining date in offer letter?  Can I include my expected date of joining while acknowledging to salary breakup?

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have an offer letter yet, do **not give notice** to your current employer.  Let you potential new employer know that you *cannot give notice until you receive a written offer*.

Also let your potential employer know that you will be able to start at the end of a minimum *[insert time span here]* notice that you need ( or should ) give to your current employer.

I would focus more on when you will be giving your notice as one date, and the start date with your new employer as another.  The salary break down should be easily handled by your new employer.

Answer (score 2):

As above, giving notice without a signed offer letter is a really, really bad idea.

That said, I would just send an email to your new employer stating that the leaving process is taking longer than expected, and you will be available to start on X day.  If they really want you to join, then an extra week is not going to be an issue.

**Your main priority right now should be getting that offer letter ASAP**